# how to use multidimensional feature vector in neural network of opencv

Tags: python, opencv, neural-network, surf

I want to use SURF feature for Neural Network from Opencv.

I have successfully extracted features and created a nn.

But, the point where I am stocked is for every images I get varying length of feature vectors and each of 128 values.

So, my question is how should I feed these values into my 128 nodes of input layers for a single image. I know how to assign the output values for each set of input sets

Thank, you